# Should I use docker-compose up or run?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a reason to use `run` to start up a `docker-compose.yml` file or should you just use `up`?

I understand that `run` can start up a specific container, but I am referring to the case where you use it without specifying a container so that it starts up all of your yml containers.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

As mentioned in [`docker-compose run`](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/17682c58db8986f1d1492559d72b3960b86f5f05/docs/reference/run.md) (2015)

> **The command passed by run overrides the command defined in the service configuration**.
> For example, if the web service configuration is started with `bash`, then `docker-compose run web python app.py` overrides it with `python app.py`.

> The second difference is the `docker-compose run` command **does not create any of the ports specified in the service configuration**.
> This prevents the port collisions with already open ports. If you do want the service's ports created and mapped to the host, specify the --service-ports flag:

```
$ docker-compose run --service-ports web python manage.py shell
```

So unless you have those specific needs (overriding a command or running only one container on different ports), `docker-compose up` (even for one container) is enough.

As noted in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066528/should-i-use-docker-compose-up-or-run/33066676?noredirect=1#comment124777957_33066676) by [questionto42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11154841/questionto42), it you are doing this for testing:

> Do not forget to add `--rm` after the `run`, else you create containers each time you run `docker-compose run ...`, that do not get removed after exit.
> This can lead to a long list of containers when you are not aware of this and test around for a while.

---

> Can you help explain why or when you would not want the ports to be created? That is why or when they might conflict with already open ports

Simply because `docker-compose run` is made to run one-off commands for your services.
That means that, if you already did a `docker-compose up`, all your containers are already running on their specified ports from `docker-compose.yml`.
Doing a `docker-compose run` at this stage (to execute a one-off command), if it was respecting the same port, would fail immediately. Hence the default non-creation of those ports.

---

Another use case (in [Compose environment variables reference](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/d577cd6877f9f8480f13cdbba3f2cf17e9c3d5eb/docs/env.md)):

> To see what environment variables are available to a service, run `docker-compose run SERVICE env`.

---

Most recent (2023) version of those commands are on [`docs.docker.com`](https://docs.docker.com/):

- [`docker compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_run/)
- [`docker compose up`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/)

Comment: Do not forget to add `--rm` after the `run`, else you create containers each time you run `docker-compose run ...` that do not get removed after exit. This can lead to a long list of containers when you are not aware of this and test around for a while. :)

Comment: @questionto42 Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @questionto42 Thank you again. I have fixed those, err... typos.

Answer (score 41):

There is an answer from [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/faq/#whats-the-difference-between-up-run-and-start).

> Typically, you want `docker-compose up`. Use `up` to start or restart all
>   the services defined in a `docker-compose.yml`. In the default
>   “attached” mode, you see all the logs from all the containers. In
>   “detached” mode (`-d`), Compose exits after starting the containers, but
>   the containers continue to run in the background.
>
> The `docker-compose run` command is for running “one-off” or “adhoc”
>   tasks. It requires the service name you want to run and only starts
>   containers for services that the running service depends on. Use `run`
>   to run tests or perform an administrative task such as removing or
>   adding data to a data volume container. The `run` command acts like
>   `docker run -ti` in that it opens an interactive terminal to the
>   container and returns an exit status matching the exit status of the
>   process in the container.

Comment: @goonerify That's not correct. `docker compose run` will actually create and start a new container, it will "execute commands against an (already) running container".

Answer (score 34):

I'd like to point out that if you're using Python with the pdb debugger:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

It will not drop to the shell if you execute your script using:

```
docker-compose up
```

However if you use run, it will drop down to the debugger as expected:

```
docker-compose run
```

Comment: Interesting, is there any explanation for why this occurs?