# How to setup unit test in Docker for nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, docker, mocha.js, docker-compose

I am trying to run mocha unit test for my node application. The application is built by a docker image.

Docker image:

```
FROM node:6.10.0-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Docker compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web: #### nodejs image
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./app/         
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    build:  ##### postgres db image
      context: .
      dockerfile: dbDockerfile
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

The setup can be built and worked as expected. The problem is not I am sure how to run unit test commands like `mocha` to perform the test.

I see a module called `dockunit` but I am not sure if that's the only way for now. Can anyone help me out about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `docker` (and `docker-compose`), you can run arbitrary commands in a container. The `Dockerfile` defines the default command that is run when no other command is specified, but that doesn't mean it's the only one you can run.

In your case: `npm start` is run when no other command is specified. That happens when you do `docker-compose up`.

But, you can run any command using `docker run` or `docker-compose run`. For your tests, that might look like this: `docker-compose run web mocha`.

There is a slight difference in `up` and `run`, and I encourage you to read up on it: [Should I use docker-compose start up or run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066528/should-i-use-docker-compose-start-up-or-run)

Does this help you get started?