# Use docker as test environment

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035974/how-to-setup-unit-test-in-docker-for-nodejs-application), but slightly different, and I don't figured out how to do it.

Like in the accepted answer was said, I know that I can pass commands to a container, but my scenario is this:

```
// Dockerfile

FROM node:8.9

LABEL maintainer="..."

ADD . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install --production

ARG PORT=10000

EXPOSE $PORT

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

So, I'm installing **only production dependencies** to the container, this way my container is lighter, but I cannot run tests in it.

Do I need another Dockerfile for testing purposes?

I thought a tricky solution for this. Using an argument, but it doesn't look a good way to solve this. The solution would be:

```
// docker-compose.yml

version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
      - PROD='--production'
      - PORT
  apitest:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
      - PORT
```

And use the PROD var in the Dockerfile

```
// Dockerfile

FROM node:8.9

LABEL maintainer="..."

ADD . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install $PROD

ARG PORT=10000

EXPOSE $PORT

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

This way, only will be installed production dependencies in the **api** service.

Like I said, this is really tricky, so, is there an "official" or "recommended" approach that I'm not aware of? Maybe using a Dockerfile.test?

Comment: I think you should not use production docker file for testing purposes. I would recommend a separate file

Comment: There is some "standard" structure or way to name it?

Comment: testing docker file is simply testing docker file and its part of your test suite. There is no standard name for it

Comment: I tought that there would be some convention like naming the docker file "Dockerfile".

Comment: I'll add that you can use this production docker image as the base (`FROM` in the Dockerfile) for your test image, then you'll only need to install the devDependencies in your test Dockerfile and you're done.