# how to solve ports problem in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

when I've build Images from *dockerfile* it's working as usual.

*dockerfile*

```
FROM node:14.17.3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm install
CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

building from dockerfile

[image: image building]

[image: port]

*output*

[image: output in browser]

but, when I've tried to build image from *docker-compose* file  the ports isn't working

*docker-compose file*

```
version: "3.9" 
services: 
  backend:
    container_name: backend 
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
```

docker-compose build

[image: docker-compose build]

docker-compose run
[image: docker-compose run]

output
[image: output]

Comment: This question might be easier to read if you pasted the actual text output of the `docker build` and other commands.  In general, avoid pasting screen shots of terminal windows or IDEs into Stack Overflow questions; the actual command and output as text are easier to read, search, and reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `docker-compose up backend` instead of `docker-compose run backend`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33066676/413924 for more details.