# Why does "docker-compose up" exit but "docker-compse run" enters into bash shell

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

Dockerfile

```
FROM get some base image

ENV ProjectDir /workarea/svc

RUN mkdir -p $ProjectDir

WORKDIR $ProjectDir
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
    svc:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/workarea/svc
        command: ["/opt/bb/bin/bash"]
```

When I run docker-compose up it exits immediately

```
r@PW02R9F3:$ docker-compose up
Creating svc_dev_1 ... done
Attaching svc_dev_1
svc_dev_1 exited with code 0
```

But when I run "docker-compose run --rm dev" I am able to get into bash as specified in the command session of my docker-compose.yaml file

```
r@PW02R9F3:$ docker-compose run --rm dev
Creating svc_dev_run ... done
[root@ad5d3d7107b4 svc]#
```

Why is this happening? Isnt "docker-compose up" running my command "/opt/bb/bin/bash" in the docker-compose.yaml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because `docker compose run` spawns a container in interactive mode (unless specified otherwise) [by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066528/should-i-use-docker-compose-up-or-run). `docker compose up` does not.

That is of importance because when running `bash` in a container that is not in interactive mode, it just dies immediately with status code 0 not because there's an error, but because there's no input for bash (and won't be).

It's like running `docker run ubuntu` and `docker run -it ubuntu`. The latter will keep STDIN open, "listening" for commands if you will.